# What are toy examples of single-copy entanglement conversion?

Tags: entanglement

In ([Vidal 1999](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9902033)) they prove that, given any pair of pure bipartite states written as
$$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\alpha_i}|i,i\rangle,
\qquad |\Phi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\beta_i}|i,i\rangle,$$
with $\alpha_1\ge \alpha_2\ge\cdots\ge \alpha_n$, $\beta_1\ge \beta_2\ge\cdots\ge \beta_n$, the maximum probability of converting $|\Psi\rangle$ into $|\Phi\rangle$ by means of any local strategy is given by
$$P(\Psi\to\Phi) = \min_{\ell\in[1,n]} \frac{\sum_{i=\ell}^{n}\alpha_i}{\sum_{i=\ell}^{n}\beta_i}.$$
What are some toy examples to better understand the idea behind the strategy, and the optimality proof?

Comment: "Toy examples" and "optimality proof" feel a bit contradictory ... (Note that the optimality proof for LOCC protocols involves proving first that *one* round (actually half round) of communication suffices ... now this can indeed also be illustrated by examples, though I don't feel this would be any more insightful than the general proof.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I disagree. One can certainly find explicit examples and specialise the proof to find the optimal conversion protocols. I personally find it easier to grok the intuition behind a calculation knowing how it applies to a number of specific toy examples showing the ideas involved

Comment: I think the proof that LOCC can be condensed to a single round is one of the arguments which is more annying to write down with qubits than in the general case (or you just take the general case and replace $d$ by $2$). Do you know the proof?

Comment: ... that being said, I would argue the question is too broad. Giving an example how to do conversion and the optimality argument are two entirely different things.

Comment: (On the other hand, if you meet me next to a blackboard, I will be happy to explain both through examples.)

Answer (score 2):

I always rather enjoyed the examples in this paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9905071

They are more stated in terms of deterministic conversion, but you could just as well calculate probabilities of conversion in the ones that cannot be done deterministically.